# Securing eval function

Tags: javascript

I have written two applications:

1. JS script attached on different websites
2. Management panel for me

Each script will create different DOM structure using JS, I can create javascript code doing this for each website from management panel.

Thus I have to keep this part of code in the database, and use eval in each script to run it.

The sample eval looks like this:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = "Fjkdfjdf";
html = {
   container: container
};
doAction();
```

So first I create DOM elements, then I attach some of them to the attribute in my script, then I call some function in my script - attaching these elements to body. The script looks like this:

```
(function() {
   var module = (function() {
      var html = ();
      var fire = function() {
         Api.getStyles(function(response) {
            eval(response.script);
         };
      };
      var doAction = function() {
         document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(html.container);
      };
      return {
         fire: fire,
         doAction: doAction
      };
   });
   module.fire();
)();
```

Is this safe enoough? Can someone override doAction() method and do whatever he wants?

Comment: Javascript can be executed from the browser console so as for security it should be more focused server-side.

Comment: I agree with NewToJS : you must consider your whole JavaScript source as unsecure : one can easily change code, variables and add breakpoints with developper tools like Chrome, FF.

Comment: Ok, I guess limiting eval content to just some comments on the server-side should be enough.